# knockout js - Table sorting using column headers

Tags: knockout.js, html-table

I'm new to knockout js & need help workout how to dynamically sort a table using the column header.

Following is part of my code:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind="click: sortFunction">
            <th id='id'>Id</th>
            <th id='name'>Name</th>
            <th id='description'>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: deptList">
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: id" /></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: name" /></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: description" /></td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In my view model I've the following function which I use to sort a data table using the table header.

**ViewModel:**

```
self.deptList = ko.observableArray(mylist);
self.sortColumn = ko.observable("id");
self.isSortAsc = ko.observable("True");

var Dept = function(id, name, description) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.description = ko.observable(description);
};

var mylist = [
    new Dept(1, "Dept 1", "D1"),
    new Dept(2, "Dept 2", "D6"),
    new Dept(3, "Dept 3", "D3"),
    new Dept(4, "Dept 4", "D4")
];

self.sortFunction = function(data, event) {

    if (self.sortColum === event.target.id)
        self.isSortAsc = !self.isSortAsc;
    else {
        self.sortColumn = event.target.id;
        self.isSortAsc = "True";
    }

    self.deptList.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (self.sortColum === 'id') {
            if (self.isSortAsc)
                a.id < b.id ? -1 : 1;
            else
                a.name < b.name ? 1 : -1;
        } else if (self.sortColum === 'name') {
            if (self.isSortAsc)
                a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1;
            else
                a.name < b.name ? 1 : -1;
        } else(self.sortColum === 'description') {
            if (self.isSortAsc)
                a.description < b.description ? -1 : 1;
            else
                a.description < b.description ? 1 : -1;
        }

    });
};
```

Even though above code is working I think there should be a better way to do this (I mean passing the column id as a parameter) which will be useful when there is a large of columns.

I tried `left[self.sortColumn] < right[self.sortColumn] ? -1 : 1`, which didn't work as expected.

If it is possible to sort via a dynamic column name please show a sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38):

Here is a quick bindingHandler that you can add to your th's. Upon clicking the th it will sort the column according the property name as defined in the binding.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sort = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var asc = false;
        element.style.cursor = 'pointer';

        element.onclick = function(){
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var prop = value.prop;
            var data = value.arr;

            asc = !asc;

            data.sort(function(left, right){
                var rec1 = left;
                var rec2 = right;

                if(!asc) {
                    rec1 = right;
                    rec2 = left;
                }

                var props = prop.split('.');
                for(var i in props){
                    var propName = props[i];
                    var parenIndex = propName.indexOf('()');
                    if(parenIndex > 0){
                        propName = propName.substring(0, parenIndex);
                        rec1 = rec1[propName]();
                        rec2 = rec2[propName]();
                    } else {
                        rec1 = rec1[propName];
                        rec2 = rec2[propName];
                    }
                }

                return rec1 == rec2 ? 0 : rec1 < rec2 ? -1 : 1;
            });
        };
    }
    };
```

This is a little more elegant in that you don't have to create a separate function for each column. A more complete working example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/brendonparker/6S85t/

Comment: because my properties were observable I needed to wrap the calls to left[prop] and right[prop] with ko.unwrap.

Comment: See updated snippet and fiddle. I enhanced it a bit to handle sorting on properties that are themselves observables.

Comment: For those looking to use brendonparker's code, if your property is a knockout observable, you will have to specify your binding like this: data-bind="sort: {arr: array, prop: field()}". Note the () after the field name. Otherwise it will be sorting on the memory address of the accessor function.

Answer (score 2):

```
left[self.sortColumn] < right[self.sortColumn] ? -1 : 1
```

doesn't work because self.sortColumn is a ko.observable on which you have to get the value by calling it as a function.

```
self.deptList.sort(function (a, b) {
  if(self.isSortAsc())
     a[self.sortColumn()]() < b[self.sortColumn()]() ? -1 : 1;
  else
     a[self.sortColumn()]() < b[self.sortColumn()]() ? 1 : -1;
});
```

and also you need to set values on observables like

```
if(self.sortColum === event.target.id)
                    self.isSortAsc(!self.isSortAsc());
                else
                {
                    self.sortColumn(event.target.id);
                    self.isSortAsc("True");
                }
```

instead of

```
if(self.sortColum === event.target.id)
                    self.isSortAsc = !self.isSortAsc;
                else
                {
                    self.sortColumn = event.target.id;
                    self.isSortAsc = "True";
                }
```

I have put together a working example

```
<table class="dept_table">
  <thead>
      <tr data-bind="click: sortFunction">
          <th id='id'>Id</th>
          <th id='name'>Name</th>
          <th id='description'>Description</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody data-bind="foreach: deptList">
      <tr>
              <td><span data-bind="text: id" /></td>
              <td><span data-bind="text: name" /></td>
              <td><span data-bind="text: description" /></td>
      </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
// deptlist data
var mylist = [
            {id:1, name:"Dept 1", description: "D1"},
            {id:2, name:"Dept 2", description: "D6"},
            {id:3, name:"Dept 3", description: "D3"},
            {id:4, name:"Dept 4", description: "D4"}];

// Deptlist-item Viewmodel
var Dept = function (data) {
  var self = this;

  for(var key in data){
    // this is the lazy approach usually you should only use observables where they are needed
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key))this[key] = ko.observable(data[key]);
  }
};

// Deptlist Viewmodel
var Deptlist = function(table_data){
  var self = this;

  this.deptList = ko.observableArray([]);
  this.sortColumn = ko.observable("id");
  this.isSortAsc = ko.observable(true);

  for(var i = 0;i < table_data.length;i++){
    if(table_data.hasOwnProperty(i))this.deptList.push(new Dept(table_data[i]));
  }

  this.sortFunction = function(){
    if(self.sortColumn() === event.target.id)
        self.isSortAsc(!self.isSortAsc());
    else
    {
        self.sortColumn(event.target.id);
        self.isSortAsc(true);
    }

    self.deptList.sort(function (a, b) {
            if(a[self.sortColumn()]() < b[self.sortColumn()]())return !self.isSortAsc();
            else return self.isSortAsc();
    });
  }
};

var deptList = new Deptlist(mylist);

ko.applyBindings(deptList,$('.dept_table')[0]);

</script>
```

Comment: and use real boolean values instead of "true" and "false" as non empty strings evaluate to true

Comment: Thanks a lot for your instructions & the sample code. The above sample does work when I specify (data, event) as function parameters. (this.sortFunction = function(data, event){). But it's supposed to sort ids in descending order if I initially click Id column itself. But strangely gives values 3, 1, 2, 4. I need 4,3,2,1 instead (for descending order of Ids). Could you please double check on this? Thanks again.

Comment: make sure that in the comparison function you access values like
a[self.sortColumn()]() < b[self.sortColumn()]()

and not like

a[self.sortColumn()] < b[self.sortColumn()]

Comment: self.deptList.sort(function (a, b) {
                
 if(self.isSortAsc())
     return a[self.sortColumn()]() < b[self.sortColumn()]() ? -1 : 1;
 else
     return a[self.sortColumn()]() < b[self.sortColumn()]() ? 1 : -1;                  
});                                                              The above function does work. Thanks!

Comment: self.deptList.sort(function (a, b) { if(self.isSortAsc()) return !(a[self.sortColumn()]() < b[self.sortColumn()]()); else return (a[self.sortColumn()]() < b[self.sortColumn()]()); });

should be enough :)

Comment: Yes both has the same logic. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @brendonparker for your awesome bindingHandler.

I've extended it a little further to also handle which table header is active and then apply a `sorting` class on the element, as well as a `asc`. This way you can use CSS to display to the end user if the table header is sorting and if it's set to asc or desc.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sort = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {


        var asc = ko.observable(false);

        var value = valueAccessor();
        var prop = value.prop;
        var data = value.arr;

        if(!bindingContext.$data['currentClicked'])
        {
            bindingContext.$data['currentClicked'] = ko.observable();
        }


        var isActive = ko.computed(function()
        {
            return (bindingContext.$data['currentClicked']() === prop)
        });


        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
                    css: {'sorting': isActive, 'asc': asc}
                }, bindingContext);


        element.onclick = function(){

            asc(!asc())

            bindingContext.$data['currentClicked'](prop);                       

            data.sort(function(left, right){
                var rec1 = left;
                var rec2 = right;

                if(!asc()) {
                    rec1 = right;
                    rec2 = left;
                }

                var props = prop.split('.');

                for(var i in props)
                {
                    var propName = props[i];
                    var parenIndex = propName.indexOf('()');

                    if(ko.isWriteableObservable(rec1[propName]))
                    {
                        rec1 = rec1[propName]();
                        rec2 = rec2[propName]();
                    } else {
                        rec1 = rec1[propName];
                        rec2 = rec2[propName];
                    }
                }

                return rec1 == rec2 ? 0 : rec1 < rec2 ? -1 : 1;
            });
        };
    }
};
```