# View doesn't update on observablearray.remove(item) in knockout without call to applyBindings

Tags: entity-framework, mvvm, knockout.js, html-table

I am learning to use MVC 4/MVVM/Knockout for a web-managed data project.  I have been running into a problem updating the View when using the remove function on an observable array.  The updates happen when using push or unshift, but not remove.  Using the debugger in chrome I can see that the data is being removed from the array, the update event just isn't working.

Snippet from the html is the table below, there is a form I did not include for adding or editing data.

```
<div id="MessageDiv" data-bind="message: Message"></div>
<div class="tableContainer hiddenHead">
    <div class="headerBackground"></div>
    <div class="tableContainerInner">
        <table id="adapter-table" class="grid" data-bind="sortTable: true">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="first">
                        <span class="th-inner">Name</span>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <span class="th-inner">DeviceID</span>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <span class="th-inner"></span>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <span class="th-inner"></span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'AdaptersTemplate', foreach: Adapters }">
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script id="AdaptersTemplate" type="text/html">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: DeviceID"></td>
                <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.selectItem">Edit</a>
                <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.deleteItem">Delete</a>
            </tr>
        </script>
    </div>
    <input type="button" data-bind='click: addAdapter' value="Add New Adapter" />
    <input type="button" data-bind='click: saveAll' value="Save Changes" id="SaveChangesButton" />
</div>
```

My javascript has been set up to manage the VM as restful and caches the changes.  Add, Edit, and Saving/Deleting data all seems to work without throwing errors that I am seeing in the debugger in Chrome.  Confirming changes seems to work fine and makes the changes to the database as expected.

```
$(function () {
    var viewModel = new AdaptersModel();
    getData(viewModel);
});

function getData(viewModel) {
    $.getJSON("/api/AdapterList",
    function (data) {
        if (data && data.length > 0) {
            viewModel.SetAdaptersFromJSON(data);
        }
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
}

//#region AdapterVM
function Adapter(name, siFamily, deviceIDs) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    self.DeviceID = ko.observable(deviceIDs);
    self.ID = 0;
}

function AdaptersModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Adapters = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.DeleteAdapters = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.NewAdapter = ko.observable(new Adapter("", "", "", ""));

    self.Message = ko.observable("");

    self.SetAdaptersFromJSON = function (jsData) {
        self.Adapters = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsData);
    };

    //#region Edit List Options: confirmChanges
    self.confirmChanges = function () {
        if (self.NewAdapter().ID == 0) {
            self.Adapters.push(self.NewAdapter());
        }
    };
    //#endregion

    //#region Adapter List Options: addAdapter, selectItem, deleteItem, saveAll
    self.addAdapter = function () {
        self.NewAdapter(new Adapter("", "", "", ""));
    };

    self.selectItem = function (item) {
        self.NewAdapter(item);
    };

    self.deleteItem = function(item) {
        self.DeleteAdapters.push(item.ID());
        self.Adapters.remove(item);
    };

    self.saveAll = function () {
        if (self.Adapters && self.Adapters().length > 0) {
            var filtered = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Adapters(),
                function(adapter) {
                    return ((!isEmpty(adapter.Manufacturer())) &&
                        (!isEmpty(adapter.Name())) &&
                        (!isEmpty(adapter.DeviceIDs()))
                    );
                }
            );

            var updateSuccess = true;
            if (self.DeleteAdapters().length > 0) {
                jsonData = ko.toJSON(self.DeleteAdapters());
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/AdapterList",
                    cache: false,
                    type: "DELETE",
                    data: jsonData,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function () { updateSuccess = true; },
                    error: function () { updateSuccess = false; }
                });
            }

            var jsonData = ko.toJSON(filtered);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/AdapterList",
                type: "POST",
                data: jsonData,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    self.SetAdaptersFromJSON(data);
                    updateSuccess = true && updateSuccess;
                },
                error: function () { updateSuccess = false; }
            });

            if (updateSuccess == true) { self.Message("Update Successfull"); } 
            else { self.Message("Update Failed"); }
        }
    };
    //#endregion
}
//#endregion

ko.bindingHandlers.message = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).hide();
        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, valueAccessor);
        $(element).fadeIn();
        $(element).fadeOut(4000);
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.sortTable = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(element).addClass('tablesorter');
            $(element).tablesorter({ widgets: ['zebra'] });
        }, 0);
    }
};

function isEmpty(obj) {
    if (typeof obj == 'undefined' || obj === null || obj === '') return true;
    if (typeof obj == 'number' && isNaN(obj)) return true;
    if (obj instanceof Date && isNaN(Number(obj))) return true;
    return false;
}
```

The specific script portion that is failing to update my html table is:

```
self.deleteItem = function(item) {
    self.DeleteAdapters.push(item.ID());
    self.Adapters.remove(item);
};
```

Everything seems to work except for the remove, so I seem to be at a loss for what to look at next, and I am too new to javascript or knockout to know if this is a clue:  If I run ko.applyBindings() command in the self.deleteItem function, I get the update to happen but it does give me an unhandled error:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: ReferenceError: Message is not defined;
>   Bindings value: message: Message

Message was defined in the VM before binding... was there something I missed in all this?

Comment: Could you add to your question the HTML which uses your custom message binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a lot of help solving surrounding issues but nothing actually solved the "why" of the problem.  The updates worked perfectly sometimes but not other times.  When I was troubleshooting it and started to get it dumbed down and working in JSFiddle I didn't include the `data-bind="sortTable: true"` in all my working versions.  Apparently, if you sort a table or using the code as I did it will not work.  The example code I have seen floating around is here at http://jsfiddle.net/gregmason/UChLF/16/, pertinent code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tableSorter = {
    init: function (element) {
        setTimeout(function () { $(element).tablesorter(); }, 0);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); //just to get a dependency
        $(element).trigger("update");
    }
};
```

The errant behavior can be obvious by clicking the delete link on the row.

- If you click on the row without sorting, you will see the row disappear correctly.
- If you first click on a column to re-sort in a different order, THEN delete the row, it remains in the table and appears to have cached.

This can be handled by binding each of the table headers instead of the table itself and replacing the `tableSorter` code with a custom `sort` behavior as discussed in this thread: 
[knockout js - Table sorting using column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932259/knockout-js-table-sorting-using-column-headers).  The sort replacement is here:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sort = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var asc = false;
        element.style.cursor = 'pointer';

        element.onclick = function(){
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var prop = value.prop;
            var data = value.arr;

            asc = !asc;
            if(asc){
                data.sort(function(left, right){
                    return left[prop]() == right[prop]() ? 0 : left[prop]() < right[prop]() ? -1 : 1;
                });
            } else {
                data.sort(function(left, right){
                    return left[prop]() == right[prop]() ? 0 : left[prop]() > right[prop]() ? -1 : 1;
                });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This has fixed my sorting/editing/deleting issues and a working jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/gregmason/UChLF/18/

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning of your Js file you are defining var viewModel = new AdaptersModel(); but lower you are stating that function Adapter() is the view model in your region declaration.  It is making your code difficult to read.  I am going to take another stab at what you can do to troubleshoot, but I would suggest that your viewmodel contains the adapters and your model contains a class-like instance of what each adapter should be.

The specific error you are getting is because you are binding Message() to something and then deleting Message().  One thing you could do to trouble shoot this is to change your div to something like :

```
<div id="MessageDiv" data-bind="with: Message">
    <h5 data-bind="message: $data"><h5>  
</div>
```

If you could create a fiddle I could give a more definite example of why, but basically if Message() is blank the with binding should not show the header which is undefined after deletion.

What you probably need to do though is look at what is being sent as 'item' and make sure it is not your viewmodel.

```
    self.deleteItem = function(item) {
        console.log(item);   // << Check console and see what is being returned
        self.DeleteAdapters.push(item.ID());
        self.Adapters.remove(item);
    };
```

You are probably deleting more than just a single adapter.

This will lead you the right direction, but I would seriously consider either renaming your code.

Comment: missing template?  The only thing I  `form` that I use for editing or adding new adapters... if I can figure out how to get it all replicated in jsfiddle I will link that asap.

Comment: Nevermind, you edited to include where you use the Binding Handler lemme take a look at it.

Comment: I adjusted my answer to give you a better direction.  Let me know how this works for you and if you get a fiddle up and running

Comment: I think you are correct with the MessageDiv issue, after the message is wiped out the push statements no longer updates to the table.  As far as the console.log goes `Adapter {Manufacturer: function, Name: function, SiFamily: function, DevIDs: function, ID: 0…}` shows that it was the adapter as intended.

Comment: Yeah it is kind of taking a stab in the dark at it, but it is difficult to try to see what is going on.  I see that your ID = 0 which means that you are never giving it a value after setting it, are you sure all of your adapters don't have the exact same ID (0) and therefore they are all being deleted?

Comment: ID=0 was an item added to the array, the array as provided from entity framework has the ID populated.  All items with id=0 are added to the table in the DB update.  I think there are two actual issues here, one with the saveAll() function creating an issue and another with the remove()... they are the only two items seeming to cause an issue.  I probably won't have the problem in fiddle till tomorrow or really late tonight to look at as I am modifying out issues as we find them.

Comment: Your delete statement says item.id()

Comment: Make Message $data.Message and see what happens to your other UI bindings.  This will ignore when Message is blank and let your UI continue binding

Comment: I changed the html bind to `<div id="MessageDiv" data-bind="message: $data.Message"></div>` and all updates now work, you definitely nailed it where the problem was.  I can't get the message to show right now but I am pretty sure that fix is easy now that everything else seems to work.