# Preserving and hinting about the sort order when updating data?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

When updating data inside a model, is it possible to preserve the sort order (jsfiddle at the end)? I have the following markup:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-bind="sort: { arr: Records, prop: 'Name' }">Name</th>
      <th data-bind="sort: { arr: Records, prop: 'Number' }">Number</th>
      <th data-bind="sort: { arr: Records, prop: 'Desc' }">Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: Records">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Number"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Desc"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: changeMe">Remove</button>
<button data-bind="click: resetMe">Reset</button>
```

Now, the sort itself is implemented using `bindingHandlers` from this [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932259/knockout-js-table-sorting-using-column-headers):

```
var recs = [];

ko.bindingHandlers.sort = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var asc = false;
        element.style.cursor = 'pointer';

        element.onclick = function(){
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var prop = value.prop;
            var data = value.arr;

            asc = !asc;
            if(asc){
                data.sort(function(left, right){
                    return left[prop] == right[prop] ? 0 : left[prop] < right[prop] ? -1 : 1;
                });
            } else {
                data.sort(function(left, right){
                    return left[prop] == right[prop] ? 0 : left[prop] > right[prop] ? -1 : 1;
                });
            }
        }
    }
};

function ViewModel(){
  var self = this;
  self.Records = ko.observableArray();

    self.changeMe = function() {
        self.Records.pop()
    }

    self.resetMe = function() {
        var recs = []
        recs.push({Name: 'Bob', Number: 1, Desc: 'I am awesome'});
        recs.push({Name: 'Joe', Number: 2, Desc: 'Another description'});
        recs.push({Name: 'Mitch', Number: 3, Desc: 'Something'});
        recs.push({Name: 'Steven', Number: 4, Desc: 'Yo'});
        self.Records(recs);   
    }
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
recs.push({Name: 'Bob', Number: 1, Desc: 'I am awesome'});
recs.push({Name: 'Joe', Number: 2, Desc: 'Another description'});
recs.push({Name: 'Mitch', Number: 3, Desc: 'Something'});
recs.push({Name: 'Steven', Number: 4, Desc: 'Yo'});
recs.push({Name: 'Robin', Number: 6, Desc: 'Hello'});
recs.push({Name: 'Batman', Number: 7, Desc: 'Description'});
recs.push({Name: 'John', Number: 5, Desc: 'Ok'});
viewModel.Records(recs);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

For instance, consider this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Legend/xgEdg/1/) and the following series of interactions:

- Click on a column so that the rows are sorted by that column. Click on "Number" twice so that it gets sorted in descending order.
- Now, hit "Reset" to simulate an ajax call (i.e., assume I'm updating the model). Now, the sort order is restored to the original.

How can I preserve the sort order i.e., remember the fact that it should be sorted by "Number" in descending order? And, of course, show this in some way next to the column? Something similar to how [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) does it (notice the up and down arrow next to each column name).

Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe take a look at the solution I offered you?

Answer (score 0):

Made a try, but there should be a better way.

The point is I made a 'dataUpdated' flag, so every time the data is updated, you sort them again.
Also, I hold in an observable object the 'prop' and the 'order' so you can also do stuff when they change ( have an arrow icon for example and change it according to the order )

Check it out

--> http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/xgEdg/15/

```
var recs = [];
ko.bindingHandlers.changed = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        if(viewModel.dataUpdated()){
            console.log('data updated, sorting...');
            sortThis(viewModel.Records,viewModel.sortData().order,viewModel.sortData().col);
        }
        viewModel.dataUpdated(false);
    }
}

ko.bindingHandlers.sort = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var order = 'none';    //    initial order status for this column

        if(!viewModel.Records.dataSort){
            viewModel.Records.dataSort = { col: 'none', order: 'none' };
        }

        element.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        element.sortAsc = element.sortAsc || false;

        element.onclick = function () {
            var value = valueAccessor(),
                prop = value.prop,
                data = value.arr;

            // sortData updated
            viewModel.sortData({
                col: prop,
                order: order = (order === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc')
            });

            sortThis(data, order, prop);
        }
    }
};

//    function for sorting the observable array
function sortThis(data, order, prop){

    if (order === 'asc') {
        data.sort(function (left, right) {
            return left[prop] == right[prop] ? 0 : left[prop] < right[prop] ? -1 : 1;
        });
    } else {
        data.sort(function (left, right) {
            return left[prop] == right[prop] ? 0 : left[prop] > right[prop] ? -1 : 1;
        });
    }
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Records = ko.observableArray();
    self.sortData = ko.observable({
        col: "none",
        order: "none"
    });
    self.dataUpdated = ko.observable(false);    //    flag for data updating

    self.changeMe = function () {
        self.Records.pop();
    }

    self.resetMe = function () {

        self.Records.removeAll();
        self.Records.push({
            Name: 'Bob',
            Number: 1,
            Desc: 'I am awesome'
        });
        self.Records.push({
            Name: 'Joe',
            Number: 2,
            Desc: 'Another description'
        });
        self.Records.push({
            Name: 'Mitch',
            Number: 3,
            Desc: 'Something'
        });
        self.Records.push({
            Name: 'Steven',
            Number: 4,
            Desc: 'Yo'
        });
        //    trigger the dataUpdated 'event'
        self.dataUpdated(true);

    }
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();

recs.push({
    Name: 'Bob',
    Number: 1,
    Desc: 'I am awesome'
});
recs.push({
    Name: 'Joe',
    Number: 2,
    Desc: 'Another description'
});
recs.push({
    Name: 'Mitch',
    Number: 3,
    Desc: 'Something'
});
recs.push({
    Name: 'Steven',
    Number: 4,
    Desc: 'Yo'
});
recs.push({
    Name: 'Robin',
    Number: 6,
    Desc: 'Hello'
});
recs.push({
    Name: 'Batman',
    Number: 7,
    Desc: 'Description'
});
recs.push({
    Name: 'John',
    Number: 5,
    Desc: 'Ok'
});
viewModel.Records(recs);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```